# How to add Currency and SettlType to InstrmtMDReqGrp in MarketDataRequest <V>

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I'm implementing a FIX program as initiator that connect to market and send & receive fix messages. In one step I need send MarketDataRequest message to market, but something happened that the message is rejected by market.

I have tried add Fields Currency.FIELD and SettlType.FIELD, but in final message in the final message they do not appear.

I need send message like:

8=FIXT.1.1 9=222 35=V 34=1013 49=**** 52=20190117-17:23:48.670 56=**** 128=FGW 262=MD1 263=0 264=5 265=1 266=Y 146=1 55=GGAL 48=GGAL-0002-C-CT-ARS 167=GO 207=XMEV 15=ARS 63=2 267=9 269=0 269=1 269=2 269=4 269=5 269=7 269=8 269=B 269=3 10=215

But I can not put the tag 15 and 63 before the tag 267.

My code now:

```
InstrmtMDReqGrp instrmtMDReqGrp = new InstrmtMDReqGrp();
NoRelatedSym noRelatedSym = new NoRelatedSym(1); //146          

instrmtMDReqGrp.set(noRelatedSym);

SettlType settlType = new SettlType(); // 63
settlType.setValue("2");

Currency currency = new Currency(); // 15
currency.setValue("ARS");       


instrmtMDReqGrp.setField(Currency.FIELD, currency);
instrmtMDReqGrp.setField(SettlType.FIELD, settlType);
```

In the final message these fields do not appear.

I'm  using quickfixj with quickfixj-spring-boot-starter 2.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting to call `addGroup` on the message, like so:

```java
fixMessage.addGroup(instrmtMDReqGrp);
```

---

A small documentation page exists for [repeating groups in QuickFIX/J](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.0.0/usage/repeating_groups.html), which demonstrates this:

> ## Creating Messages With Repeating Groups
>
> Here is an example of a message that distributes market data. When the
>   message is created the required field with the number of repeating
>   groups is set to zero. This is because QuickFIX will automatically set
>   this field for you when you add groups. This way there is never an
>   inconsistancy between the number of entries in the field and in the
>   message.
>
> ```
> package quickfix;
>
> quickfix.fix42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh message =
>   new quickfix.fix42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh(new Symbol("QF"));
>
> quickfix.fix42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries group =
>   new quickfix.fix42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries();
>
> group.set(new MDEntryType('0'));
> group.set(new MDEntryPx(12.32));
> group.set(new MDEntrySize(100));
> group.set(new OrderID("ORDERID"));
> message.addGroup(group);
>
> group.set(new MDEntryType('1'));
> group.set(new MDEntryPx(12.32));
> group.set(new MDEntrySize(100));
> group.set(new OrderID("ORDERID"));
> message.addGroup(group);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What's reject fix message you get back? It usually gives the tag number that contains the error plus some error description.

Usually the structure of fix messages is defined by a data dictionary provided by the `Acceptor`. If this data dictionary differs from the one built in the quickfixj library, you will need to recompile quickfixj core library with this data dictionary so messages are parsed correctly but also tags are placed in the correct order when creating new messages.